# How do I delete a part of the line in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

So this is the line:

```
UPDATE `traffic`.`traffic_log` SET `fb_adgroup_id`='888197766666640010238881977,748062737,install,2017-12-25 06:51:34,1,0,,0,,255.164.216.69 -  -  [25/Dec/2017:06:51:34  0000] GET /backendServer/app/post/install?token=8bbbbbbbf6asd8eeeeeee6c48fe3f111&mob_channel=Pinterest_Bidalgo:_battelship_android&isInstall=true&is_impression=1&appUniqueIdentifier=f85c0134cfdc38a8e8b1e413eeb186f354361028f85c0134cfdc38a8e8b1e413eeb186f35432341028&pinterest_ID=88819776666664 HTTP/1.0 200 0
```

It's a very big sheet. I need to delete everything from the first "-" in the middle of the line until the end of the line. alt+click is just not realistic in this amount of lines.

Comment: It's a single line so mark it and press delete.

Comment: Hi seth, there are 100000 lines similar to this one.

Comment: So add it to your question. Currently it's just about deleting a part of a line in Notepad++. Toto provided an answer that suites both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `-.+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
-   : literally a dash
.+  : 1 or more any character but newline
$   : end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
UPDATE `traffic`.`traffic_log` SET `fb_adgroup_id`='888197766666640010238881977,748062737,install,2017
```

Comment: @YuvalBanon: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: @YuvalBanon: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers